# Running docker from github actions can't find file added during previous step

Tags: docker, github-actions

This will be a decent read so I thank you a lot for trying to help :bow:

I am trying to write a github action configuration that does the following two tasks:

1. Creates a `autodeploy.xar` file inside the build folder
2. Use that folder along with all other files inside to create a docker image.

The build process can not find the folder/files that the previous step has created. So I tried three things:

1. Try to use the file created in the previous step (within the same job in github actions) but couldn't get it to run.

   - The build process threw an error that complained that the file doesn't exist: `Error: buildx failed with: error: failed to solve: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3658977881/build/autodeploy.xar: no such file or directory`
2. Try to build two jobs, one to initiate the file and the other that `needs` the first one to build the docker. However, this gave the same error as step 1.
3. Try to build the docker image from task 1

   - This step is just running a bash script from the github actions.
   - I tried to run `docker build .` from inside the shell script, but the github actions complained with  `"docker build" requires exactly 1 argument.`
   - I was providing the right argument because on echoing the command I clearly saw the output `docker build . --file Dockerfile --tag ***/***:latest --build-arg ADMIN_PASSWORD=***`

This must be something very trivial, but I have no idea what's going wrong. And I think a solution to either one of these approaches should work.

Thanks once again for going through all this. Please find the GH actions, workflow.sh and the docker file below:

The GitHub actions yml file:

```
name: ci

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - 'build'

jobs:
  docker:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Set up JDK 11
        uses: actions/setup-java@v3
        with:
          java-version: '11'
          distribution: 'temurin'

      - name: Login to DockerHub
        uses: docker/login-action@v2
        with:
          username: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME }}
          password: ${{ secrets.DOCKERHUB_TOKEN }}

      - name: Run script to replace template file
        run: |
          build/workflow.sh
        
      - name: Build and push
        uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
        with:
          push: true
          tags: ${{secrets.DOCKERHUB_USERNAME}}/${{secrets.REPO_NAME}}:latest
          build-args: |
            ADMIN_PASSWORD=${{secrets.ADMIN_PASSWORD}}
```

The workflow file:

```
# run the ant
ant <--------- This command just creates autodeploy.xar file and puts it inside the build directory


#### I TESTED WITH AN ECHO COMMAND AND THE FILES ARE ALL THERE:
# echo $(ls build)
```

The docker file:

```
# Specify the eXist-db release as a base image
FROM existdb/existdb:6.0.1

COPY build/autodeploy.xar /exist/autodeploy/    <------ THIS LINE FAILS
COPY conf/controller-config.xml /exist/etc/webapp/WEB-INF/
COPY conf/exist-webapp-context.xml /exist/etc/jetty/webapps/
COPY conf/conf.xml /exist/etc

# Ports
EXPOSE 8080 8444

ARG ADMIN_PASSWORD
ENV ADMIN_PASSWORD=$ADMIN_PASSWORD

# Start eXist-db
CMD [ "java", "-jar", "start.jar", "jetty" ]
RUN [ "java", "org.exist.start.Main", "client", "--no-gui",  "-l", "-u", "admin", "-P", "", "-x", "sm:passwd('admin','$ADMIN_PASSWORD')" ]
```

The error saying file was not found:

```
#5 [2/6] COPY build/autodeploy.xar /exist/autodeploy/
#5 ERROR: lstat /var/lib/docker/tmp/buildkit-mount3658977881/build/autodeploy.xar: no such file or directory
#4 [1/6] FROM docker.io/existdb/existdb:6.0.1@sha256:fa537fa9fd8e00ae839f17980810abfff6230b0b9873718a766b767a32f54ed6
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

this is dumb, but the only thing I needed to change was the `context: .` in the github actions

```
- name: Build and push
  uses: docker/build-push-action@v3
  with:
    context: .
```

Comment: OMG, thanks, this one helped me after hours of madness..

Comment: same here... thanks a lot

Comment: I gave up for a couple days came back to it, and found this post!